# How should eliminate the multiple socket io connection in React form submit?

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to make a Countdown timer. I want to send a timer from **Admin** page to the server. The issue here is that every button hit in the input field make a new connection. I want only one connection and send a timer value. I tried put the *const socket* inside the *submitHandler* function but in that case also created a new connection for every submit. And also when I refresh the **Admin** page the "*transport close*" appears multiple times in the console. It depens how many times I sent the "*send-timer*" event.
I am also using react router in this project.

Here is my **Admin** page:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import styles from './Admin.module.scss';

const Admin = () => { 

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState("");  
  const socket = io('http://localhost:5000'); // server port
  
  const submitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send-timer', timer)
    setTimer("")
  }

  const timerChangeHander: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    setTimer(e.target.value);    
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.admin}>
      <h1>This is admin page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
        <input placeholder='Timer' onChange={timerChangeHander} value={timer} />
        <button type='submit' value='Send'>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>   
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

This is my **Server** code:

```
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server,{ 
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}) //in case server and client run on different urls

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log('client connected: ',socket.id)
  
  socket.join('clock-room')
  
  socket.on('send-timer', timer => {
    console.log(timer);
  })

  socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
    console.log(reason)
  })  
})

const getTime = (date) => (
  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
)

setInterval(()=>{
  io.to('clock-room').emit('time', getTime(new Date()))
}, 1000)

server.listen(PORT, err => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log('Server running on Port ', PORT)
})
```

Any help would be great!